# Typescript unexpected null | undefined instead of string | null

Tags: typescript

I have class Foo that implements interface IFoo and instances are type of IFoo. Constructor arguments come as IFoo object. For this purpose i use following code:

```js
interface IFoo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nullableProp: string | null;
}

class Foo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nullableProp: string | null;

  constructor({
    name= 'Default name',
    age = 35,
    nullableProp = null,
  } = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age ;
    this.nullableProp = nullableProp;
  }
}

const fooData: IFoo = {
  name: 'Lalala',
  age: 42,
  nullableProp: 'StringValue'
};

const foo = new Foo(fooData); //error at this line
```

And then I recive error (as on the screenshot attached).
[image: Error screenshot]

Please help me to understand what's going on there and how to fix it :)

UPD: possible solution:

```js
interface IFoo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nullableProp: string | null;
}

class Foo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nullableProp: string | null;

  constructor({
    name= 'Default name',
    age = 35,
    nullableProp = null,
  }: Partial<IFoo>= {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age ;
    this.nullableProp = nullableProp;
  }
}

const fooData: IFoo = {
  name: 'Lalala',
  age: 42,
  nullableProp: 'StringValue'
};

const foo = new Foo(fooData);
```

Comment: Your constructor accepts a parameter of type `{ name?: string | undefined; age?: number | undefined; nullableProp?: null | undefined; }`, but you provided it with an argument of type `IFoo`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gNyHJwOXECupARtCyIguAGxFxeIiAAUomAA5Va9EA2QAfbmJYBffPgTjq1ZFhwEhZTssaC2HKsL4DWwsRKmyFSuow1aRFlYETBBlLgQwTCgAChhsZAoMbABKPFYiMAALYGoAOhJyZABeZHjMAqs7TJz89hRS8rz65GrkbNyC0XFJGTl5ErLsLvder3k7PT0DUNohzAARODA4KmScUotiKyoAcgAZOHFxXYAaVnqqABYAJnOhbo8+72RdgGVfVQA1I64IXfwOiCITCYHmgxAEAA7qZsHFsEsVikmMgAPSo6ByKBsMEdEwiUAQIA

Comment: Okay, I should probably explain what kind of behavior I expect from this class. The type of the created object must be IFoo, while the constructor takes an object of the same type, but in the absence of any of its properties, it replaces them with the default value (one of the specified in the IFoo type for this property).
I found this solution, it seems to work. How correct is it? (code goes after UPD in original post)